# Is there a way to modify the database side of a .where() query within the query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Basically, I have a DateTime stored in the format "2020-01-01 00:05:00 UTC", but I need to compare only the timeless date (first) portion of it with my params[:date] (which is in the format "2020-01-01").

Is there a way to do something like:

```
@events = Event.where(date.to_s.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/): params[:date])
```

Where the database side of the query has been manipulated at runtime to be only part of the actual stored data?

If not, how else would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

for your problem above, you can do with this way

```
@events = Event.where("DATE(date) = ?", params[:date])
```

this command above will compare date part from datetime field, Function Date(..) is part of SQL command

if params[:date] is string, you can do with this way

```
@events = Event.where("DATE(date) = ?", params[:date].to_date)
```